Dynamic graph on excel
I need to plot a dynamic bar graph in Excel that contains three identical bars where I can modify the width of the bars and the distance between them. Additionally, I want to repeat the same three bars again after a specified distance between the two sets, as shown in the picture below.
I want to be able to set the width of the bars, the distance between the bars, and the distance between the two sets from cell values so that I can easily modify them.
How can I achieve this in Excel?
Thank you!

I tried to do it by my self on excel but I don't get the expected results


Have you tried adjusting the x-axis values? Some q&a on here show some things that might be useful.

Yes I tried but It didn't work as I expected I could not modify the width and the space between bars

With the Overlap and the Gap Width parameters the following result can be reached.

